# Call only first request UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3, deep-linking

I have one url request let say

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/share?referCode=RSJDofpeW")
```

and we want to open this url in WebView and this link is also associated with the universal links. So opening this url will open the installed application but i want to load the page in UIWebView. So i checked the delegates and found that at first time it calls it is the above url then next time it will add scheme and appstore redirection.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        log.verbose(webView)
        log.verbose(request)
        log.error(navigationType.rawValue)
        if request.url?.scheme == "itms-appss" || request.url?.scheme == "googleApp"{
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

So to overcome the issue of not loading the page in Web View i did the code like above so when scheme is `itms-appss` or `googleApp` it will not load the request but for the first time when it was correct url it should load that page but that is not opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Check

```
 var isUrlLoaded : Bool = false;
```

//delegate functions

```
  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
//check is the url is loaded for first time or not           
 if isUrlLoaded != true{
                if request.url?.scheme == "itms-appss" || request.url?.scheme == "googleApp"{
                    return true
                }
            }

            return false
        }
        func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
            if  webView.request?.url?.scheme == "itms-appss" || webView.request?.url?.scheme == "googleApp"{
         // is url loaded       
         isUrlLoaded = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried this but the page is not loading

Comment: Your recent edit will make the itms-apps and googleApp to open and not the webpage.

Comment: Firstly this url will hit https://www.google.com/share?referCode=RSJDofpeW and then followed by itms and googleApp